# Getting rid of unused color in ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

When using ggplot to plot my data a pink line underneath "Graft" in the legend appears. What is causing this and how do I get rid of it? Added below is the code utilized to create the plot, followed by an image of the plot and finally a snippet of the data used.

Thank you

```
 library(ggplot2
 p <- ggplot(Height, aes(x=DAT, y=Height, color=Graft, shape=Graft)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, fullrange=T)
p
```

[image: ggplot height over time]

```
  DAT   Graft   Height
7   C   11
7   C   12
7   C   12.5
7   C   9
7   C   11.5
7   C   11.5
7   C   11.5
7   C   10
7   C   12
7   C   13
7   C   11
7   C   11
7   C   12
7   C   11.5
7   C   12
7   C   12.5
7   C   13.5
7   C   11
7   C   13
7   C   11
7   C   13
7   C   12.5
7   C   10
7   C   12
7   B   13
7   B   13
7   B   13
7   B   12
7   B   12
7   B   12
7   B   7.5
7   B   7
7   B   9
7   B   10
7   B   10.5
7   B   10
7   B   14
7   B   14
7   B   15
7   B   11.5
7   B   12
7   B   14
7   B   11.5
7   B   12
7   B   11.5
7   B   8
7   B   7.5
7   B   9
7   S   11
7   S   12
7   S   12.5
7   S   11
7   S   12.5
7   S   12
7   S   13
7   S   13
7   S   13
7   S   14
7   S   11.5
7   S   11.5
7   S   10
7   S   12.5
7   S   13
7   S   12.5
7   S   13
7   S   14
7   S   14
7   S   13
7   S   12
7   S   12
7   S   13
7   S   12
14  C   21
14  C   21
14  C   21
14  C   16
14  C   21.5
14  C   21
14  C   23.5
14  C   19
14  C   21
14  C   24
14  C   18
14  C   20
14  C   21
14  C   20.5
14  C   21
14  C   23
14  C   23
14  C   22
14  C   20
14  C   19
14  C   22
14  C   22.5
14  C   22
14  C   18
14  B   22
14  B   23
14  B   20
14  B   20.5
14  B   20.5
14  B   19
14  B   13.5
14  B   12
14  B   12
14  B   17
14  B   20
14  B   17
14  B   23
14  B   24
14  B   26
14  B   20.5
14  B   21
14  B   23
14  B   23
14  B   23
14  B   21
14  B   11
14  B   12
14  B   12
14  S   15
14  S   20
14  S   22
14  S   19.5
14  S   19
14  S   20
14  S   22
14  S   21.5
14  S   21
14  S   21
14  S   19
14  S   18
14  S   19
14  S   21
14  S   22.5
14  S   21.5
14  S   22
14  S   23
14  S   23
14  S   22
14  S   19
14  S   18
14  S   23
14  S   19
```

Comment: Please post an MWE. The data you posted do not generate the problem you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `Graft` is a factor. A legend item is created for each level of the factor. Call `levels(Height$Graft)` to check which levels are present in in the factor, I guess there is an level `""` (empty string).

This level could have been created when you were reading in your data and there was an empty line, but I can only guess without a full reproducible example.